# How to put a dynamic drop-down list in Eclipse Kepler toolbar?

Tags: java, eclipse, dynamic, drop-down-menu, eclipse-kepler

I'm working on an Eclipse plug-in.

With Indigo, a drop-down list in the toolbar like the one below works perfectly.

[Drop-down list in the toolbar, the currently selected item is shown when the list isn't open](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1Hru.png)

It is built like this (where the `MyList` instance is dynamically constructed):

```
org.eclipse.ui.menus
  (menuContribution) locationURI : toolbar:org.eclipse.ui.main.toolbar
    Functions (menu) id : xxxx
      (dynamic) id : yyyyyyy
        class MyList extends ContributionItem
```

However, this doesn't work on Kepler, and it's difficult to understand why.
While I can write a dynamic drop-down list which work in main menu (`menu:org.eclipse.ui.main.menu`),
my list with the same code doesn't appear if locate it in toolbar (`toolbar:org.eclipse.ui.main.toolbar?additions`).

How can I create a drop-down list like the one in the screenshot above in Eclipse Kepler's toolbar, and handle events when items are clicked?

Comment: I think I am struggling with exactly the same issue at the moment. I have a class that extends ContributionItem and one that extends ControlContributionItem and I'm adding them to toolbars by using <dynamic> in my plugin.xml. This used to work in Eclipse 3.7. However the contribution classes aren't constructed in Eclipse Kepler (4.3.1).

Comment: Perhaps this "NEW" bug report means that this simply hasn't been created yet in the compatibility layer:https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=316470

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be a compatibility issue in Eclipse 4.x. I can already reproduce the problem in a very simple example. I reported this as [a bug] you can vote on this bug if you like.

EDIT: Eclipse committer Paul Webster confirms that this doesn't work yet. It may be possible to work around this by using  instead of  and extending WorkbenchWindowControlContribution instead of ContributionItem.

EDIT: SlowStrider's bug ([427475](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=427475)) was closed as duplicate of bug [392457](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=392457); so if you want to vote on this issue, vote here: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=392457. The older bug ([392457](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=392457)) is fairly old and has only one vote. (M.)